# xmlparsing in jenkins script using XMLParser

Tags: jenkins, xml-parsing, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am trying to read the server name from the xml file in a pipeline script.

**My Code:**

```
node {

   def str = "<root><HTTPTargetConnection><Loadbalancer><server name=\"myserver\" /> </Loadbalancer></HTTPTargetConnection></root>";

   def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(str);

   echo rootNode.HTTPTargetConnection.Loadbalancer.server.@name.value[0];

}
```

**Exception:**
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
*

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   unclassified field groovy.util.Node HTTPTargetConnection  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:367)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:363)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into sandbox issues.  The field in question is not authorized for use and therefore must be approved (in the script approval page).

Comment: I thought the same, but in fact it was never showed up in script approval page.

Comment: check again after a reboot - I've seem weird behavior with this.  Also, you might consider using XMLSlurper instead to see if that works.  If you have the same problem you can put the code into a function that you put into a globally shared library and that will avoid the sandbox check.